# Microsoft Mobile Broadband API Error : Maximum PDP Context activation limit reached

Tags: windows, mobile, com

Good Afternoon.

I have an issue with mobile api broadband on Windows 7.The issue is apparent accross all connection managers within windows, also it returns the same error when using the mbapi COM layer.

The issues can be seen clearly when using metsh command as shown below.

```
 netsh>mbn show int

 There is 1 interface on the system:

  Name               : Mobile Broadband Connection
  Description        : Sierra Wireless Mobile Broadband Network Adapter
  GUID               : {6B09E77F-3421-4074-9A80-4F6A500B28D3}
  Physical Address   : 00:a0:c6:00:00:00
  State              : Connected
  Device type        : Mobile Broadband device is embedded in the system
  Cellular class     : GSM
  Device Id          : 355096040782731
  Manufacturer       : Sierra Wireless Inc
  Model              : MC8305
  Firmware Version   : D3200-STSUGN-1575 0e090008
  Provider Name      : TMO UK
  Roaming            : Not roaming
  Signal             : 65%

netsh>mbn show prof

Profiles on interface Mobile Broadband Connection:
-------------------------------------
TMO UK

netsh>mbn connect interface="Mobile Broadband Connection" connmode=name name="TMO UK"

Connect Failure: Maximum PDP Context activation limit reached.
```

I have searched for any answers but as yet have not been able to find any thing that may indicate what may be the reason for this error.

The mbapi raises an exception (PDP context exceeded) on the following syntax ( which was working ok)

```
            IMbnConnection conn = inf.GetConnection();

            // CONNECT HERE - Results checked in ConnectionEventsSink : IMbnConnectionEvents
            conn.Connect(MBN_CONNECTION_MODE.MBN_CONNECTION_MODE_PROFILE, "TMO UK", out requestID);
```

This is in line with the error raised from the application code.

This issue has only come to light yesterday (06/06/2013) and may have some connection with the fact the Provider ID has changed from EE ZONE to TMO UK.

Any Information of this or simalar issues would be greatly apreciated.

Thanks Sarah

Comment: Looks like it behaves like it was already connected. Have to tried to call inf.Disconnect()? Stupid question: have you tried to reboot?

Comment: Yes tried all of that, the netsh example was also tried with disconnect first but with no luck.